# Getting the off-screen cell frame after a layout change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uicollectionview

I have two view controllers. The first one, MainVC, contains a UICollectionView with a flow layout, and is the root view controller of a UINavigationController. The second one, DetailVC, is pushed onto the navigation stack.

The flow layout shows items in a grid, where the itemSize depends on the view controller's view size, so I update the itemSize when the device rotates. I do that this way (in MainVC):

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *) _collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    flowLayout.itemSize = [self itemSizeForSize:size]; // method that calculates new item size
    [flowLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

This works as intended. When I'm in MainVC and I rotate, the cells resize accordingly, and when I rotate in DetailVC and navigate back, the cells have been properly resized.

The problem is that before I pop the DetailVC, I need to get the frame of a specific cell (for a custom transition), which may or may not be visible. I can't use -cellForItemAtIndexPath: because it may return nil. So I use this (in MainVC):

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [_collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(attributes.frame));
```

But if I have performed a rotation in DetailVC, this always logs CGRectZero. It seems like the cell frames aren't recalculated until the collection view is onscreen again, which is a problem because I need them before that. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is `_collectionView`, `collectionViewLayout`, or `attributes` nil? What happens if you force the view to load by calling `[toVC view];`?

Comment: None of them are nil. Loading the view has no effect either...

Comment: @rits Am having the same prob.  Trying to get the cell frame coming back in my transition after rotation.  Did you solve this?